# How do I merge duplicate nodes as I load them in from multiple csv files?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Sorry if this is difficult to parse, have only been using NEO4j for a few days.
I'm trying to build a database from multiple csv files. 'styles.csv' includes notable architects and buildings. The architect and buildings csv files have additional info on their respective entries.

#### Examples of data structures

##### Styles csv

[image: Styles csv snapshot]

##### Buildings csv

[image: Buildings csv snapshot]

##### Architects csv

[image: Architects csv snapshot]

However, when I import the csv files sequentially it creates duplicate nodes for each node with the same name value. For example, [here it is creating a node for the 'roman' style.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5RN1.png)

I am loading each csv sequentially and unwinding where there are cells with multiple values.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///restructured_data_styles.csv' AS stylesheet
MERGE (s:Style {Style: stylesheet.Style, Dates: stylesheet.`Dates`, Location: stylesheet.Location})
WITH s, stylesheet
UNWIND split(stylesheet.`Examples`, ';') AS stylebuildings
MERGE (buildings:Building{name:stylebuildings})
MERGE (s)-[rbs:BUILT_IN_STYLE]->(buildings)
```

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///restructured_data_architects.csv' AS architectsheet
MERGE (a:Architect {Architect: architectsheet.Name, Born: architectsheet.Born, Died: architectsheet.Died, Description: architectsheet.Description})
WITH a, architectsheet
UNWIND split(architectsheet.`Buildings`, ';') AS architectbuildings
MERGE (buildings:Building{name:architectbuildings})
MERGE (a)-[rab:NOTABLE_PROJECTS]->(buildings)
```

What I want is to load each csv and have neo4j add the additional information provided by each csv file, but also merge the duplicate nodes created while maintaining the relationships already present.
As it stands, the relationships built within files are fine, but I'm having trouble linking these nodes and relationships *between* the csvs. Does that make sense? Will clarify further if not! Thanks!

Nodes are being created, but they don't merge based on their name values. Have looked into APOC refactoring but I am very new to this (and also not a data scientist!) - a dumbed down explanation would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Your graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5RN1.png) is inconsistent with the Cypher code you have shown. It has have a `Style` node that has a `name` property and is missing `Style`, `Dates`, and `Location` properties. You need to fix what is creating these inconsistent `Style` nodes, since `MERGE (s:Style {Style: stylesheet.Style, Dates: stylesheet.`Dates`, Location: stylesheet.Location})` will never match such a `Style` node.

#### Some MERGE best practices

1. Multiple [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) clauses for the same label should all specify the same set of properties, since a `MERGE` clause with more properties will not match a node created by a `MERGE` clause with fewer properties.
2. Ideally, a `MERGE` clause should only specify the minimum properties needed (if any) to uniquely identify a node (or relationship).

   For example, instead of:

   ```
   MERGE (a:Architect {Architect: architectsheet.Name, Born: architectsheet.Born, Died: architectsheet.Died, Description: architectsheet.Description})
   ```

   it would be safer to use this (assuming architect names are unique -- which is a bad assumption, by the way):

   ```
   MERGE (a:Architect {Architect: architectsheet.Name})
   ON CREATE SET s += {Born: architectsheet.Born, Died: architectsheet.Died, Description: architectsheet.Description}
   ```

   or, even better, since architects can have the same name (but this option requires your non-Architects csv files to reference an architect using an id instead of a name):

   ```
   MERGE (s:Style {id: architectsheet.archId})
   ON CREATE SET s += {Architect: architectsheet.Name, Style: Dates: stylesheet.`Dates`, Location: stylesheet.Location}
   ```
3. Do not use `MERGE` when you do not have data for all the properties needed to populate the node.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance - I've now set up IDs in each sheet where I want another node to be referenced, but I am having difficulty working between the sheets - in your third code block I'm not able to call s as a variable within the architectsheet as I seem to only be able to have one csv open at a time - when I use a WITH statement instead of closing stylesheet with a semicolon, the database does not load at all.

Comment: You did not show a query that has 2 `LOAD CSV`s. Perhaps you can create a new question that shows what you are now trying to do.